# Dataset of spirometric surveys

Tags: medical

For a school project I am making an analytical engine for a [spirometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirometry) platform (pulmanary function test, measuring lung function). The idea is that measurements made with our spirometer infrastructure automatically get uploaded to a database, where meaningful statistical operations can be conducted.

As we don't have a deployed physical product yet, we also don't have a data set. Nonetheless, I would like to have a representative (not necessarily big) set of data across ages, sexes, ethnicities... This will allow us do perform demonstrations and perform tests of how the analytics and visualisations work on real-world data.

Specifically, I'm looking for a data set that has per entry (person):

- FVC (Forced Vital Capacity) - Critical
- FEV (Forced Expiratory Volume) - Critical
- Age - Very important
- Sex - Very important
- Ethnicity / length / other factors - Very welcome but not required

Comment: Welcome to SX, you don't have to say "Thank you" on every post. In fact it is generally appreciated if you don't  to keep the posts clean and simple. If you want to thank someone, use the buttons